# Concatenate multiple column names into 1 column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am struggling with small problem here. I have a table with 4 columns

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
NULL.........NULL.........NULL.........NULL
ABC..........NULL..........XYZ...........NULL
```

Column 1,2 & 3 may have some value or null, column4 is null
When any of the column1,2 or 3 are not null, I have to update column4 with that column name. I am expecting following result

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
NULL.........NULL.........NULL.........NULL
ABC..........NULL..........XYZ...........Column1,Column3
```

Can anyone guide me how can I achieve this result.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry! I am trying in SQLServer

Comment: Why do this in the database? You're denormalizing for what seems to be a presentation feature. The kind of logical operation you're describing should be done at the client side and only for presentation such as UI or reports. Denormalizing in a db is usually done only for performance reasons. And besides, .Net, Java and other class libraries have classes built-in that make this kind of logic much easier to implement.

Comment: If you want something similar to `GROUP_CONCAT` then look into `STUFF()`. This [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case to test for null values and return the column name when it is not null.
The stuff is there to remove the extra comma you get first in the string.

```
update YourTable 
set Column4 = stuff(case when Column1 is not null then ',Column1' else '' end +
                    case when Column2 is not null then ',Column2' else '' end +
                    case when Column3 is not null then ',Column3' else '' end, 1, 1, '')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3499f3/1)